# wine is not installing properly on kali 2

Tags: kali-linux, wine

I am trying to install wine on Kali and I type to commands that offsec recommends and then this happens

command: `sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386 && apt-get update && apt-get install wine-bin:i386`

> error:Ign:1      Reading package lists... Done
>   Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree        Reading
>   state information... Done Some packages could not be installed. This
>   may mean that you have requested an impossible situation or if you are
>   using the unstable distribution that some required packages have not
>   yet been created or been moved out of Incoming. The following
>   information may help to resolve the situation:
>
> The following packages have unmet dependencies:  wine-bin:i386 :
>   Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not going to be installed
>                    Depends: libwine-bin:i386 (= 1.4.1-4) but it is not going to be installed E: Unable to correct problems, you have held
>   broken packages.

Answer (score 0):

You have dependencies issues. Basically, Wine isn't compatible with your current libc6 package version. You should try to upgrade your system packages using `apt-get dist-upgrade` and try again.